# Making Properties of a object as Nullable type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is that a good practice when i need to pass DBnull by properties.To make them as a nullable type. Cause when we need to Pass Null value to Backend by our  Variables.We made them as Nullable.But is This okay With Properties also.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, you really have no choice. For example the T-SQL `bit` data type (which is a type `BOOL` in .NET); in T-SQL, it can be NULL, 0 or 1. So, you have to set it as a NULLABLE type, as such:

```
public bool? MySqlBitField { get; set; }
```

Update: I did a quick reference of the book Framework Design Guidelines (Cwalina, Abrams), from Addison Wesley, of Nullable types, and their usage. I've pasted some text from the book. Btw, I would highly recommend the book as a good general reference.

**From the book:**

CONSIDER using Nullable to represent values that might not be present (i.e., optional values). For example, use it when returning a strongly typed record from a database with a property representing an optional table column.

DO NOT use Nullable unless you would use a reference type in a similar manner, taking advantage of the fact that reference type values can be null.

For example, you would not use null to represent optional parameters.

```
// bad design
public class Foo {
   public Foo(string name, int? id);
}

// good design
public class Foo {
   public Foo(string name, int id);
   public Foo(string name);
}
```

AVOID using Nullable to represent a general three-state value. Nullable should only be used to represent truly optional Boolean values: true, false, and not available. If you simply want to represent three states (e.g., yes, no, cancel), consider using an enum.

AVOID using System.DBNull. Prefer Nullable instead.

**Note from Pablo Castro**

Nullable is in general a better representation of optional database values. One thing to consider though is that while Nullable gives you the ability to represent null values, you don’t get database null operational semantics. Specifically, you don’t get null propagation through operators and functions. If you deeply care about the propagation semantics, consider sticking with DBNull.